# Assembler can't open file

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

After assembling the MINI-44.asm, I tried to run MINI-44.com_. Then it showed "unable to open file". Then I copied all the files in MyBuild to MySource and vdrive\c for just in case. But either it's not locating any files or unable to open files. How do I fix this?

```
;#MAKE_EXE#
.model small
.code
FNAME equ 9EH
ORG 100H
START:
MOV AH,4EH;
MOV DX,OFFSET COM_FILE;
INT 21H;
SEARCH_LOOP:
JC DONE;
MOV AX,3D01H;
MOV DX,FNAME; 
INT 21H;
XCHG AX,BX;
MOV AH,40H;
MOV CL,42H;
MOV DX,100H;
INT 21H;
MOV AH,3EH;
INT 21H;
MOV AH,4FH;
INT 21H;
JMP SEARCH_LOOP;
DONE:
RET;
;COM_FILE DB 'C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C\*.com_',0;
;COM_FILE DB 'C:\EMU8086\MyBuild\*.com_',0;
COM_FILE DB '\MySource\*.com',0;
;COM_FILE DB '\vdrive\C\*.com_',0;
;COM_FILE DB '\MySource\*.com_',0;
;COM_FILE DB 'C:\EMU8086\MySource\*.com_',0;
END START;
```

Comment: Please post code as text in your question

Comment: If you are generating an EXE file remove the `org 100h` line from your file.

Comment: I am trying to generate COM file

Comment: If you want a proper COM file you will need to remove the `;#MAKE_EXE#` line at the top and change `.model small` to `.model tiny`

Comment: It generates COM file but cannot open other COM files as before. still shows the same error. "Interrupt error: 21h/3Dh:cannot open file."

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check that the bytes in memory really are the path string you want?  I assume emu8086 doesn't process backslash-escapes inside strings the way C does, or you'd need double-backslash.

Comment: I have installed emu8086 on C:\emu8086 and all the COM files I want to open is on C:\emu8086\MyBuild. Assembly files is in C:\emu8086\MySource. Now which one is the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the things already mentioned in Michael Petch's and Peter Cordes' comments:

You should not use a fixed address (`9Eh`) but a label for the file name.

If you modify the code, the address is no longer correct. Using a label will fix this.

And `9Eh` **cannot** be the correct address because a `.com` file starts at address `100h`, so all addresses inside the `.com` file must be at least `100h`.

It is not sure what is located at address `9Eh` (it is an address inside the address space reserved for the command line; however, this address is not used if the command line arguments are less than ~20 bytes long). However, obviously the data stored at `9Eh` is not a file name!

So it is clear that you'll get a "file not found" error because the `dx` register contains `9Eh` but there is no valid file name at address `9Eh`.

Answer (score 2):

To compile to a .COM file all you need is:

```
.model tiny
ORG 100h
```

The DOS.SearchFirst function needs the `CX` parameter. In order to search for any normal files specify `CX=0`:

```
 mov ah, 4Eh
 xor cx, cx
 mov dx, offset COM_FILE
 int 21h
 jc  Done
```

Use this ASCIIZ filespec with wildcard:

```
COM_FILE db 'C:\EMU8086\MyBuild\*.com', 0
```

Since the default DTA (Disk Transfer Area) is at 80h, you're right to say: `FNAME equ 9EH`.
If DOS found any matching file, its ASCIIZ filename will be at address 9Eh.

If however the DTA address was changed (normally that's something you would have done yourself via [function 1Ah](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-1a.html)) you need to use the other address. You can always retrieve the current DTA address via [function 2Fh](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-2f.html). Result will be in `ES:BX`.

> I have installed emu8086 on C:\emu8086 and all the COM files I want to open is on C:\emu8086\MyBuild. Assembly files is in C:\emu8086\MySource. Now which one is the correct path?

If you still can't open the file it's probably because on the one hand you searched for it in a **s p e c i f i c** directory (`C:\emu8086\MyBuild`) but on the other hand you try to open it in the **c u r r e n t** directory (`???`).
The solution is to append the filename that DOS gave you to the same path that was used to ask for the file:

```
 mov si, FNAME
 mov di, FileName
More:
 lodsb
 stosb
 cmp al, 0      ;Copy includes the terminating zero
 jnz More
 mov dx, Path
 mov ax, 3D01h  ;Access write-only
 int 21h
 jc  OpenFileError
 mov bx, ax     ;Handle
```

With these data definitions:

```
COM_FILE db 'C:\EMU8086\MyBuild\*.com', 0
Path     db 'C:\EMU8086\MyBuild\'
FileName db '.............'
```

---

> ```
> MOV AX,3D01H;
> MOV DX,FNAME; 
> INT 21H;
> ```

If a file can't be opened, DOS returns the CF set. Do check this!

---

> ```
> MOV AH,40H;
> MOV CL,42H;
> MOV DX,100H;
> INT 21H;
> ```

.Writing can fail. Check the CF!
.The size parameter is `CX` not just `CL`.

---

> ```
> DONE:
> RET
> ```

Although this works here (.COM program with an intact stack) you should make it a habbit to use the correct program termination code:

```
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
```